# How to change default trust setting in Asp.Net Core 3.1 web.config file?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I deployed my Asp Net Core 3.1 project on a server provided by a hosting company. Firstly, there was no problem with my project but my hosting company has changed IIS security options. **Full** trust option is converted to **Medium**. After that when I enter my web site I get **500 Internal Server Error**. What can I do? How to change default Asp Core Trust options?

Error:

**HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error**

The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<location path="." allowOverride="true">
        <system.web>
        <securityPolicy>
            <trustLevel name="Full" policyFile="internal" />
            <trustLevel name="High" policyFile="web_hightrust.config" />
            <trustLevel name="Medium" policyFile="web_mediumtrust.config" />
            <trustLevel name="Low" policyFile="web_lowtrust.config" />
            <trustLevel name="Minimal"
                        policyFile="web_minimaltrust.config" />
        </securityPolicy>
        <trust level="Medium" originUrl="" />
    </system.web>
    <system.webServer>
        <httpErrors errorMode="Detailed" />
        <handlers>
            <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule" resourceType="Unspecified" />
        </handlers>
        <aspNetCore processPath=".\admin.exe" arguments="" stdoutLogEnabled="false" hostingModel="InProcess" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout">
            <environmentVariables>
                <environmentVariable name="ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT" value="Development" />
            </environmentVariables>
        </aspNetCore>
        <!-- maxAllowedContentLength = 1GB (the value is in Bytes) -->
        <security>
            <requestFiltering>
                <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="1073741824" />
            </requestFiltering>
        </security>
    </system.webServer>
</location>
```

**EDIT**

Hi again. When I enter the website a day later, I saw that my problem was solved. Why? Really, I don't know :)

Comment: Why did you tag your question as `asp.net-mvc-4`? Are you really using that framework?

Comment: Have you tried contacting your host?

Comment: Yes, they said that they couldn't help me with my project software. But, they said if I want, they could transfer my package to the "Full" level server and changed the trust level  Also, they said maybe I can ask some questions to Asp.Net developers about my problem.